# ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, utf-8, postgresql-9.1

*I looked at similar questions, but still have not found a suitable solution.*

On my Ubuntu OS I created some database by:

```
createdb PADB -W
```

And created a table.

```
create table teacher(
    id_teacher integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(120),
    experience integer 
);

NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "teacher_pkey" for table "teacher"
```

I want to add some data contains Cyrillic, but I got this error:

```
PADB=# insert into teacher (name, experience) values ("Пупкин Василий Иванович", 15);
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd0d0
```

Here is my lc settings:

```
PADB=# select name, setting from pg_settings where name like 'lc_%';
    name     |   setting   
-------------+-------------
 lc_collate  | ru_RU.UTF-8
 lc_ctype    | ru_RU.UTF-8
 lc_messages | ru_RU.UTF-8
 lc_monetary | ru_RU.UTF-8
 lc_numeric  | ru_RU.UTF-8
 lc_time     | ru_RU.UTF-8
(6 rows)
```

What is wrong?

Postgresql 9.1.11

Comment: your mysql client probably doesn't send data in utf8

Comment: What client application are you using to connect to PostgreSQL?

Comment: BTW: `id_teacher integer PRIMARY KEY,` : id_teacher cannot be NULL, so your insert will fail since it does not supply a value for id_teacher. (did you mean `SERIAL` ?)

Comment: Also, please show the output of the `locale` command in the terminal you're running `psql` from. Edit the question and comment here when done.

Comment: @wildplasser, mb I mean SERIAL :) I worked only with sqlite previously but postgresql is not the same..

Comment: Maybe if you mean serial, you should _say_ serial. Just to keep us from guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but I really don't know which of my actions were the most useful:
1) I rebuild and reinstalled postgreSQL with readline and zlib libraries (previously I run configure with keys --without-zlib and --without-readline).
2) I started to use single quotes instead of double.
Thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your client application is actually sending data in `koi8-r` or `iso-8859-5` encoding, not `utf-8`, but your `client_encoding` is telling PostgreSQL to expect UTF-8.

Either convert the input data to utf-8, or change your `client_encoding` to match the input data.

Decoding your data with different encodings produces:

```
>>> print "\xd0\xd0".decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

>>> print "\xd0\xd0".decode("koi8-r")
пп

>>> print "\xd0\xd0".decode("iso-8859-5")
аа
```

However, rather strangely, your input doesn't appear to contain any of these. I'm a bit puzzled as to what encoding would turn `Пупкин Василий Иванович` into the byte sequence`\xd0\xd0`. So this isn't fully explained yet. In fact, I can't find *any* encoding of `Пупкин Василий Иванович` that produces that byte sequence, so I'm wondering if there's some double-encoding or similar mangling going on. I'd need to know more about your environment to say more; see comments on the original question.

Comment: I connect to the server using psql.
My locale:
`maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Place your data in a UTF-8 encoded csv file then import (`/copy`).
You could use Notepad++: `Encoding` > `Convert to UTF-8` to create the file.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay - I had only read the **title** of your question.
The answer was to be useful for googlers. I have corrected it be valid for your question now, partially.